# WP Sidebar Widgets Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I have a large multisite. Each site has custom sidebars created in the widget areas. Only a few of them, aren't updating when I revise the sidebar content. What I'm updating is the content within the text boxes, within the widget panel.

What could be causing this? I'm so confused why the problem isn't consistent site wide.

My sidebar.php file has this:
`<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar' ); ?>`

And in my functions.php file:

```
function sidebars() {

register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => 'Sidebar',
    'id'            => 'sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="rounded">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>',
) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'sidebars' );
```

**What I've Tried:**

- Deactivating plugins
- Editing, saving edited content in both widget panel and customizer panel

Comment: A few of *what* aren't updating? Sidebars on some pages / posts within a single *site*, or sidebars across different sites across the multisite? (Does it matter you have multisite)?

Comment: The sidebar widgets aren't updating. Example, I add a text box, or recent post section to my sidebar widget, click save, refresh, and those items I've added are gone. They aren't sticking. There are a handful of sites across the multi site that are showing this problem.

Comment: OK, some sites (with this same theme? Are you **sure**?) do not save the widgets when you add them in the dashboard via "Appearance" => "Widgets".  Is that correct?  Are you 100% confident all sites have the same code in their theme?

Comment: Yes, same theme throughout the whole site – 100%. I made the theme, it's custom.  The widgets will appear, but if you edit them and save, and refresh, they don't remain there. I'm so confused.